# laravel 5.1 access-control-origin for restFull api

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I'm developing RESTful API using Laravel 5.1. My endpoints are working correctly on Postman. But when I integrate it with the front-end, it is getting following the error.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://ideahubapi.dev/api/v1/users/register. 
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. 
> Origin 'http://ideahubfront.dev' is therefore not allowed
>   to access. 
> The response had HTTP status code 500.

I've tried following methods.

(1) created core middle-ware.

```
 <?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class Cors
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Requested-With');
    }
}
```

added it to **kernal.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'web' => \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        'cors' => \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    ];
}
```

and to **routes.php**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web', 'core'], 'prefix' => 'api/v1'], function(){

    // get single user by user id
    Route::get('getuserbyid/{user_id}', 'UserController@getSingleUserById');

    Route::post('users/register', 'UserController@register');

});
```

After that options requests worked. But post request still same.

(2) Added headers to controller return manually. Like this.

```
return response()->json([$user, $merchant], 200)
                ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
                ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS')
                ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Cache-Control, Connection, Date, Server, Content-Type, User-Agent,  Accept, Referer, Authorization,Origin,  Accept-Encoding, Content-Length, Host, Connection,  X-Requested-With');
```

No luck. Guys please help me. I'm dying for this. My clients wants to see the registration. I'm stuck on this.

Comment: the middleware specify in `routes.php` should be the same as in kernel. change this `['middleware' => ['web', 'cors']`

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't notice that before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web', 'core']
```

to

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web', 'cors']
```

It doesn't work since it doesn't match up with the one in the kernel.

Comment: Yeah. I changed it. But no luck

Comment: Thank you for showing me my mistake. This was one problem. Main issue was in front-end. This was helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

CORS is the name of your curse and here's a solution: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors

Comment: Thanks for your answer.